# How to bypass anti-debugging C++

Tags: x64dbg, anti-debugging, crackme, anti-dumping

So I have a crackme my friend sent to try and crack it but the problem that I cannot bypass the anti-debugging or even patching it.

I even tried using ScyllaHide at **max** settings but still it detects that there's a debugger and close itself without any message, and it encrypts its strings in memory, so I can't get the key.

How can I prevent it from detect if there was a debugger or getting the key from memory? (BTW I knew that it encrypts string being entered and compares it to the another encrypted string)

Comment: Have you tried to identify what type of anti-debugging is present in this binary ? If not, it's going to be difficult to answer your question without more details ...

Comment: in IDA there was a functions like:
UnhandledExceptionFilter
IsDebuggerPresent
CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent
CloseHandle
GetTickCount
QueryPerformanceCounter
GetModuleHandle
GetExceptionCode

and other ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a debugger, single step the code, and watch what it does.  Odds are, it's one of the windows API functions that Ahmed mentions in another response.  But, step 1 would be figure out what it's doing, and then using the debugger, just jump OVER that code.

Comment: i made a program that will gonna instead edit it in memory and it worked without patching the file itself (because it's have an Anti File-Patching anyway), but i will mark your answer as solved, because why not.